# MySQL FK violation causes mysql_query to return different values on different hosts

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I designed a simple web interface to a database on localhost.  On the localhost, if I attempted to send an SQL command to create a record, and used an invalid FK in one of the fields, then the PHP `mysql_query` returns false and I have my PHP script return the `mysql_error()` which of course has some info about the FK I tried to violate.

I moved the entire project to a HostGator account I have, and created the DB tables using the EXACT same SQL setup script.  When I try to violate a FK here though, the `mysql_query` returns true, so my PHP script acts as if the request succeeded, which of course it didn't.

In both cases, nothing gets inserted into the DB, but for some reason in the latter case `mysql_query` is returning true.  Also in the latter case `mysql_error()` appears empty, even though clearly I've made an error.

Is there a server setting somewhere that controls this?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Similar issue, on the remote server I am able to delete a record which has FK dependencies.  It seems the hostgator version is not enforcing referential integrity at all. :-(

Comment: Did you include the engine type (ENGINE=InnoDB) when creating the tables? Perhaps the default in hostgator is myisam.

Comment: You're using MyISAM tables on hostgator, which accept-and-ignore foreign key-related directives silently. You'll have to rebuild your tables to use InnoDB instead.

Comment: Thanks, you guys both rock!  Was totally unaware of the existence of such options. :-)  It works.  P.S.  One of you should respond so I can give you the green check mark dealey. :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As posted in the comments above, the correct solution here is to force my engine to InnoDB.